# How to centre an iFrame on a specific aspect of the HTML document?

Tags: html, iframe

Have created an iframe and wish to centre it on a specific area of the HTML document? E.g iframe of website, want to centre it on left hand side of the website.

Comment: What do you mean by "centre it on the left"?? That seems contradictory. A Fiddle would help to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specifying "center" or "left", but try this example and adapt to your situation :

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="yourURL" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -185px; height: 859px; margin-top: -533px; width: 926px;"/>
</div>
```

Example from [dimpost.com](http://www.dimpost.com/2012/12/iframe-how-to-display-specific-part-of.html)

Comment: In line styling is a no no.

Comment: If the OP copy and paste the answer, it's not 'alright'